# How to add header and footer in pdf using jquery datatable

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datatables

I am unable to add a header and footer in my PDF using jQuery DataTables with TableTools extension. Can anyone give me any idea?

This is my code:

```
var oTable;
var line1Value,line2Value;
var myVar = "<img src='../macro/$proj/images/images.jpg' alt='myImage' title='myImage'/>"
    \$(document).ready(function(){
        oTable=\$('#PdfTable').DataTable({
            "scrollY":"500px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":false,
            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
            "sSwfPath": "../macro/$proj/js/Pdfjs/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    "csv",
                    "xls",
                    {
                        "sExtends": "pdf",
                        'sTitle': "Benchmark Report",
                        "sPdfOrientation": "landscape"

                    },
                    "print"
                ]
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting to make it more readable.

Comment: Do you mean adding a header and footer to the table or to the PDF page when exported?

Comment: Sorry for late response..jonmrich . Yes i want to add header and footer in every page of the pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

It requires changing the swf action script file ('copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf' or 'flashExport.swf').

TableTools uses the AlivePDF library ( http://alivepdf.bytearray.org ) for creating PDFs. The AS3 code used by TableTools is here: https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/blob/master/media/as3/ZeroClipboardPdf.as.

Source: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/19049/customizing-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use header and footer property like this

$("#example").DataTable({

```
header : true,
footer: true,
```

});

This way you can enable to print header and footer.